# in python, search in a matrix the next higher number to a given number

Tags: python, matrix, find

I began with python and I need to find, in a matrix, the next higher number from a given number. Actually the value of the number is not interesting but I need its location.

For example, if my matrix is

`a = ([0.14, 0.93, 0.2], [0.1, 0.8, 0.55])`

and my given number is 0.5

How would I do to have `(3, 2)` for i and j value of 0.55 which is the next higher number from 0.5?

Answer (score 1):

You could loop over the cells in a flattened fashion:

```
>>> a = ([0.14,0.93,0.2],[0.1,0.8,0.55])
>>> [(v, (j, i)) for i, row in enumerate(a,1) for j,v in enumerate(row, 1)]
[(0.14, (1, 1)), (0.93, (2, 1)), (0.2, (3, 1)), (0.1, (1, 2)), (0.8, (2, 2)), (0.55, (3, 2))]
```

Since you also want the minimum of the elements which were > 0.5, we can do this:

```
>>> cc = ((v, (j, i)) for i, row in enumerate(a,1) for j,v in enumerate(row, 1))
>>> min(c for c in cc if c[0] > 0.5)
(0.55, (3, 2))
```

(We could cram this all into one line, but I think it's clearer to separate the enumeration from the search.)

Comment: nice, but you go 2 times through the data :)

Comment: No, you only pass through it once.  The genexp defining `cc` isn't evaluated until the `min`.

Comment: ok. m i thought the 2 sections of code were to be exec in sequence

Comment: That is perfect for me! Thanx so much!
Could you just say me how would I do to extract indices (3, 2) and use them in the end of my code?

Comment: @user2253068: assign the result of the `min` to something, like `min_val, (x,y) = min(c for c in cc if c[0] > 0.5)`.  But since Python is zero-indexed (i.e. the first element of a list is `somelist[0]`, not `somelist[1]`), and in order to access that element you'd need to use `a[1][2]`, you'd be better off thinking of it as living at `(1,2)` rather than `(3,2)`.  Your call, though.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you need to search by columns or by rows first.
Either way, you could sort the rows or columns. That way you can perform a binary search on each row/column.

Comment: Actually I need to find the next higher in the matrix. I do not know what is the difference if I began with rows or columns.
Each cell correspond to a probabilistic element and I determine a random number. I need the next higher in the matrix to do a probabilistic model and, in this way, I try to reproduce the probability of each element. This will appear if I repeat this action a lot of times. (Or I hope it will appear...)

Comment: imho there isn't any...you still need to scan everything

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you need to scan every element in the matrix...

code would look something like this:

```
num=0.5
min = 999.999 # or a large enough number
pos_i=-1
pos_j=-1

for i ...:
    for j ...:
        if a[i][j] < min and a[i][j] > num:
            pos_i = i
            pos_j = j
            min = a[i][j]
```

this has a O(n^2) complexity

you can improve with sorting the data, to about O(n log(n)), but it depends if you want to keep indices or not...